# Create a Java class that will retrieve the resource of any URL (using the HTTP protocol) and save the contents as seen by the browser, to a file

Tags: java, http

There are also several restrictions: 
You are free to use any library/technique, except for java.net.Url, java.net.URI or java.net.UrlConnection.   Solutions using these classes will not be accepted.   You are free to change the class signature for better error handling and readability.

Class outline:

```
public JGet extends Object {

public JGet( String urlToPage, String saveToFilename ){

}

     public Object getContents(){

     }

}
```

I was asked this question earlier today in an interview. While Java is not my strongest language, I gave it my best shot. After I submitted my .java file (shown below), the hiring manager responded with these comments: "You did not solve the problem at hand. Also, there was no error checking, no communication to the calling class and exceptions were masked." How does my code not solve the problem and how could I fix the problems they listed? I want to learn from my mistakes and improve. My code is below.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


public class JGet extends Object
{

String URL;

String filename;

public JGet( String URL_with_content, String filename_of_content)
{
    URL=URL_with_content;
    filename=filename_of_content;

}

//This method gets the html content of a JGet object's URL and stores it in the file located at 'filename'
//In order to accomplish this, apache's http components library was used: http://hc.apache.org/
public Object getContents()
{
    HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget=new HttpGet(URL);

    try 
    {
        HttpResponse response=client.execute(httpget);

        //getting the content of the url
        InputStream input=response.getEntity().getContent();

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filename);

        //taking inputstream and writing it to file using Apache's IOUtils library: http://commons.apache.org/io/
        IOUtils.copy(input,output);
    } 

    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        System.err.println("ClientProtocolException with "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.err.println("IOException with "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}

}
```

Comment: Were you supposed to only use JDK classes or could you use third-party libraries as you did? Otherwise this could be a good reason to fail your solution. Perhaps they were expecting a solution only using JDK classes.

Comment: @edalorzo "You are free to use any library..."

Comment: This is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexhange.com, but there is something decidedly odd about `getContents` returning an `Object` but also *always* returning `null`.

Comment: @KirkWoll I wasn't even aware that existed, whoops. And yes that is odd. I just wasn't sure what else to return from `getContents`. I guess I should have returned something to indicate that getting the contents was successful or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, I will make some comments on my interpretation of the statements. Perhaps other can comment on different aspects.

> "You did not solve the problem at hand"

It appears that your code does copy the contents of a given URL into a file. It may not be the best implementation, but it does solve the problem.

> [...] there was no error checking [...]

This could mean a lot of things:

- You could have checked if the parameters passed by the calling class were not null.
- You could have checked that the URL string actually corresponded to an HTTP URL.
- You could have checked if the provided file path existed or not.

Perhaps somewhat like

```
private final URI urlToPage;
private final String saveToFileName;

public JGet(String urlToPage, String saveToFilename) {

    if(urlToPage == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("The URL must not be null");
    }

    if(saveToFilename == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("The name of the destination file must not be null");
    }

    //some other questions we could ask
    //does this path exist? (we may let the stream creation fails later also
    //does the file exist? (ditto)
    //can we overwrite files (in this case we may stop it here)
    this.saveToFileName = saveToFilename;

    try {
            //is this actually a http URL?
            //we may check protocol
        this.urlToPage = new URI(urlToPage);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid URL provided: "+ urlToPage);
    }
}
```

> No communication to the calling class and exceptions were masked

Well, I think the problem here is that in your implementation the calling class has no way to determine if the process finished successfully or if it actually failed. You could have either use the return object to indicate success or failure or change the method to void and rethrow exceptions to the caller if anything wrong happens.

In you implementation, if you open the destiny file and it is empty, is it because the process fail or beause the URL contained nothing?

Perhaps somewhat like this:

```
public void getContents() throws IOException {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(this.urlToPage);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    IOUtils.copy(entity.getContent(), new FileOutputStream(this.saveToFileName));
}
```

Or wrap the IOException into an specialized checked/unchecked exception and throw that one.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Exception handling, I think you should rethrow exceptions and let the calling code decide what to do with it:

```
public JGet { //extends Object { not necessary

    public JGet( String urlToPage, String saveToFilename ){

    }

    public boolean getContents() throws IOExceprion {
        //returns true if successful. 
        //use try / catch to rethrow ClientProtocolException as IOException
    }

}
```